# Php shuffle part of associative array

Tags: php, associative-array, shuffle

I need to shuffle part of associative array. Example of array is below. Rules: shuffle needs to happen on same keys (ad-pre,ad-mid,ad-end). Order of key is always this (ad-pre,ad-mid,ad-end), however array may not always contain all keys (for example, there may not be ad-pre keys). So for example take all array items with keys 'ad-pre' and shuffle them and put back on same start, end index.

I ended up with this code, but its messy, and I am looking for a cleaner way. Also, next_key might not exist!

```
$data = array(
  array(
    "ad_type"=> "ad-pre",
    "type"=> "a1"
  ),
  array(
    "ad_type"=> "ad-pre",
    "type"=> "a2"
  ),
  array(
    "ad_type"=> "ad-mid",
    "type"=> "b1"
  ),
  array(
    "ad_type"=> "ad-mid",
    "type"=> "b2"
  ),
  array(
    "ad_type"=> "ad-mid",
    "type"=> "b3"
  ),
  array(
    "ad_type"=> "ad-end",
    "type"=> "c1"
    )
);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';

$sub = array();
$index = 0;
$len = 0;
$start;
$key = 'ad-mid';
$next_key = 'ad-end';
foreach($data as $row){
    if($row['ad_type'] == $key){
        if(!isset($start))$start = $index;
        $len++;
    }
    else if($row['ad_type'] == $next_key){//I want to break by next key (so it doesnt loop all array), but this is not good because this key may not exist!
        break;
    }
    $index++;
}

var_dump($start,$len);

$sub = array_splice($data, $start, $len);
shuffle($sub);
array_splice($data, $start,0, $sub);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Side note: those are values you're talking about, not keys.

Comment: "I want it somehow better" is not really a good question. What is your problem with your solution? What kind of (better) solution would you expect? Elaborate!

Comment: If I understood correctly, all your data comes in already sorted by `ad_type` key. If that is the case, `else if($row['ad_type'] == $next_key)` can simply be `else` and you don't need the `$next_key` at all. Outside of that, I see nothing wrong about your solution. For any future reference, working solutions you want to improve are more fitting for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If I remove next_key, this doesnt work, because array starts with ap-pre values, and I ask for ad-mid, so it breaks imediatelly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m assuming here that your input array *only* contains these three ad_types, resp. that you want to shuffle in *all* of them, if there are more than those three, and there is nothing else in the input array that would need to be preserved as-is.

```
// group items in a helper array, under the ad_type
$helper = [];
foreach($data as $item) {
  $helper[$item['ad_type']][] = $item;
}
// loop over the grouped ad_type arrays, shuffle their items,
// add shuffled items to result array
$result = [];
foreach($helper as $items) {
  shuffle($items);
  $result = array_merge($result, $items);
}

var_dump($result);
```